# Подключение Sqlite в VS17

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlite3, visual-studio-2017

Доброго времени суток. Появилась нужда поработать с Sqlite3 DB с помощью EF, так вот возник вопрос, как ее подключить, что бы в Server Explorer ее можно было использовать как MS sql? Какие есть альтернативы в подключении ДБ? Спасибо.
[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox#sqlite--sql-server-compact-toolbox)

Заходим в установку расширений

[image: шаг1]

Ищем и устанавливаем так

[image: шаг2]

Установленное можно найти либо в меню `TOOLS`, или в `Server Explorer`

[image: шаг3]

Выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, по ходу ожидания нагуглил эту утилиту, не через NuGet :)

Comment: @Rifter Пожалуйста. Хотя, я редко ей пользуюсь. Все больше либо дополнением к огнелису или же SQLite Studio

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, Sqlite Studio на вид удобный инструмент, схожий с Sql Management Studio

Comment: Мне, что в ней нравится, так это возможность быстро сгенерить тестовые данные для таблиц.